# Visual Studio 2013 failing to parse aspx when converting to web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

So we are in the process of converting a website to a web app.  Which requires us to "Convert to Web Application".  We are doing it file by file instead of doing the entire project at once, for good reasons.  But when I try to convert Visual Studio pops up an error that says "Could not parse the file 'blahblah\filename.aspx'".  It was working, now it just stopped working.  There are no errors in the aspx file, and I don't want to have to reinstall.

Comment: Does the codebehind and aspx file match in names and such?

Comment: Yeah, it is a good thought though.

Comment: Are there any other error messages? You might need to start simplifying the file to bare bones and start adding stuff back to get to the root of the problem is not.

Comment: It is a huge website.  100's and 100's of webpages.  I am not sure if that would be the best approach.

Comment: I'm not saying to do to all of the pages but do it to one to see what kind of issue you are dealing with. You need to first identify the why.

Comment: Oh, I got you. I will give that a shot when I get sometime.